# Cannot view gvisMotionChart from printed html file

Tags: r, google-visualization

When I save the code for a Motion Chart into an html file and try to open it, I get the footer and the "initializing" progress bar blinks for a split second, but nothing else shows up.

so

```
M1 <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", timevar="Year")
plot(M1)
```

works great, but

```
print(M1, file='d:/delete/fruit.html')
```

and then opening the resulting file in a browser comes up blank (except for the footer). Is there a way I can save this visualization and circulate it around?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem -- printing produces a working file for me. You should try printing without specifying a file, which spits out the html in your R session. You can look this over and copy it to a file if nothing is missing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I understand it, the file has to be displayed via a web server to show the chart

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart.html#Notes

> Because of Flash security settings, this (and all Flash-based
>   visualizations) might not work correctly when accessed from a file
>   location in the browser (e.g., file:///c:/webhost/myhost/myviz.html)
>   rather than from a web server URL (e.g.,
>   http://www.myhost.com/myviz.html). This is typically a testing issue
>   only. You can overcome this issue as described on the Macromedia web
>   site.

The plot command in R uses the internal R http help server to overcome this limitation.

Here's how I overcame it:

1. Go to http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html
2. Click on the dropbox which says 'Edit location' and choose 'add location'
3. Click 'browse for folder'
4. Choose the folder in which you saved your html file
5. Click OK

Now open your googleVis html file and it should display successfully. In fact, any googleVis file you open from within the folder you selected will also display as you would expect.

Comment: Amazing, thank you Tony! I'm getting to a dangerous state where I'm starting to believe there's *nothing* the good people at SO can't figure out!

Comment: @Tom no worries mate, happy to help. I had the same problem earlier this year and it took about an entire day to figure it out so hopefully I've saved you a bit of time.

Comment: Do you know of a way to fix this for people who would like to watch your plots, so that they don't have to do this procedure?

Comment: @Dualinity I don't but you could try emailing the maintainer of the package directly, or ask a new question on here. I've seen over on R-Bloggers.com people showing examples using Shiny but I haven't tried it out myself.

Comment: @TonyBreyal I found out. Two parts: 1) You need to export a bit differently than the standard `print()` and 2) you need a website (I use Dropbox)

Answer (score 1):

On Google Chrome v21 & Windows 7, there is an issue with 'browse for folder' : it will open the 'browse for files' -window which does not allow you to choose a folder correctly. For now, a workaround is to disable the PepperFlash -plugin: for details see

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!starred/chrome/qdBApWR6xPc%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score -5):

The answer before is not detail.
This problem is real cause by FLash.
but your have to change three place:
first:  Global Storage Settings panel:select Dont ask！
second：Global Security Settings panel ：select Always allow!
third:Website Storage Settings panel :select Don't ask!
After the three setting, open the html file again.I am sure you will see it !

上面的意思是：这个问题是应为flash的安全设置引起的，所以我们要设置一下，具体要设置三个方面：
第一：全局存储设置：选择不在询问
第二：全局安全设置：选择 始终允许
第三：web站点存储设置：选择 不再询问。
设置好以后，重新打开html文件。

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).