# How to save HTML file from googlevis in R

Tags: html, json, r, rstudio, googlevis

- R version: 3.2.2
- Win 8.1 both IE and Chrome

When I plot a motion chart

```
m = gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar=’Fruit’, timevar=’Year’);
plot (m)
```

I get the result on browser. I would need to save this html file somewhere for offline access. The actual need is, I have a database and created motion chart. I would like to host that file on AWS and share the URL. (simply said, I would like to access the HTML page offline)

I have tried to print (to copy the html code) and save directly via R

```
cat(m$html$chart, file="tmp.html")
```

I have also tried CTRL+S on the browser that displays the data output from Rstudio (as html file). But nothing has worked.

googleVis::gvisTable() and googleVis::gvisGauge() work just fine (static data/table, but the motion charts won't work)

Comment: Have you tried `print(m, filename="tmp.html")`? I would read the `?plot.gvis` help page.

Comment: Yeah, tried file= and also filename = tmp.html. Still no luck. I referred to the googlevis help page and also the documentation on R. I am still struggling

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009825/cannot-view-gvismotionchart-from-printed-html-file of any use?

Comment: yes. tried that too, but no luck. It has to be more than that. Not just with my system (or settings) but to get the full HTML file with data

Comment: I _just_ installed the pkg (I despise google charts and don't use them ever) and tried the _first_ example on the `gvisMotionChart` help page then printed the `M1` object to a local HTML file and fired up a local web server and the file worked _perfectly_. It _requires_ a web server context to work. It _can't_ work as a standalone HTML file you just "open".

Comment: well, @hrbrmstr , you are spot on. I could uploaded the file on my AWS account and it works neat ! Cheers mate !

Comment: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sudheerrao07/server.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/googlevis/docs/plot.gvis), html string is part of the object `m`.

Basically, using the following code, you can convert the html object into a flat string:

```
htmlstring <- paste(c(m$html$header,paste(m$html$chart,collapse = ""),m$html$caption,m$html$footer),collapse = "\n")
```

Now, you can save this `htmlstring` to a flat text file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a personal webpage on which you can share your motion charts. When the chart is plotted, click on "Chart ID" below the page, copy the HTML code and paste it in the HTML editor of the page maker.

Best,

C.B.