# gvisMotionChart() from r package googleVis generating blank plots in browser?

Tags: r, charts, googlevis

I am using `googleVis` r package for first time & referred this link for the same but getting a **blank chart** in browser:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/04/revisiting-world-bank-data-analysis-with-wdi-and-gvismotionchart/

To cross check I have also tried this on `gapminder` dataset and I am still getting a **blank chart**

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
library(googleVis)
```

```
gapminder
```

```
gap <- gvisMotionChart(data = gapminder,
                idvar = "country",
                timevar = "year",
                xvar = "gdpPercap",
                yvar = "lifeExp",
                sizevar = "pop",
                colorvar = "continent"
                ) 

plot(gap)
```

browser output:

http://..... googleVis/MotionChartID20f874d20ab.html

Have also tried:

```
cat(gap$html$chart, file = "gvis1.html")
```

From one of **SO** post it looked like there could be **flash player issues** [Cannot view gvisMotionChart from printed html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009825/cannot-view-gvismotionchart-from-printed-html-file)

And from **adobe** website it seems that `flash` is no longer supported: https://www.adobe.com/in/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html

Does that mean `googlevis` `Motion chart` won't work anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, I have the same issue and it seems that Flash is no longer supported so these graphs don't work anymore.